# Using Apache Camel for routing gRPC traffic (using the same port per route)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, grpc

I'm trying to implement a gateway using **springboot** & **apache camel** to manage routing **gRPC** traffic of multiple microservices.

The goal is to expose all the traffic using the **same** hostname & port to a single entry-point for our client.

I've started with two routes as described below

**AuthenticationRoute**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationRoute extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        AuthenticationResponse fallbackResponse = 
        AuthenticationResponse.newBuilder().setMessage("FAILED").setStatus("ORS-400").build();
            
        from("grpc://localhost:9090/com.erable.services.impl.AuthenticationService=authenticate") 
            .circuitBreaker()
                .to("grpc://localhost:4041/com.erable.services.impl.AuthenticationService?method=authenticate") 
                    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "FALLBACK ALERT")
            .onFallback() 
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(fallbackResponse, AuthenticationResponse.class))
            .end();
    }
}
```

**EquipmentListQueryRoute**

```
@Component
public class EquipmentListQueryRoute extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        EquipmentListResponse fallbackResponse = 
        EquipmentListResponse.newBuilder().setMessage("FAILED").setStatus("ORS-400").build();
            
        from("grpc://localhost:9090/com.erable.services.impl.EquipmentService=equipmentListQuery") 
            .circuitBreaker()
                .to("grpc://localhost:4042/com.erable.services.impl.EquipmentService?method=equipmentListQuery") 
                    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "FALLBACK ALERT")
            .onFallback() 
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setBody(fallbackResponse, EquipmentListResponse.class))
            .end();
    }
}
```

When running the project, I gor the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:264) ~[grpc-netty-1.30.2.jar:1.30.2]
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:183) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar:1.30.2]
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:90) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar:1.30.2]
at org.apache.camel.component.grpc.GrpcConsumer.doStart(GrpcConsumer.java:78) ~[camel-grpc-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]
... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453) ~[?:?]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[?:?]
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
```

Does this mean that I can't use the same host:port to expose multiple **camel-gRPC** routes?
This scenario works fine when using **jetty** or **netty-http** or **undertow:http** to route rest apis.

Answer (score 0):

This option is not implemented currently

Created a JIRA issue to track this functionality
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15883